# WooCommerce Email Template Customization

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, customization, hook-woocommerce

I am trying to add a paragraph on the order confirmation email for a WooCommerce site. I added the support for WooCommerce to my child theme's functions.php file. Then I copied an email template to the proper folder in my child theme. Here's the template file with my attempt. But when I test the email (via a plugin), I get, "There has been a critical error on your website." I ran the PHP through a validator, and there is one error - but I am not skilled in PHP. Can someone help me figure out what to change to add the paragraph successfully? I am working in a staging environment. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php /* translators: %s: Customer first name */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Hi %s,', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_billing_first_name() ) ); ?></p>
<?php /* translators: %s: Order number */ ?>
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'Just to let you know — we\'ve received your order #%s, and it is now being processed:', 'woocommerce' ), esc_html( $order->get_order_number() ) ); ?></p>


<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'We are busy baking your products for delivery from our kitchen to your door\. Any products ordered last week\, including over the past weekend\, are being baked this week and will ship next week\. So\, your order will be delivered in 3 to 10 days from the date of your order\. Look for another email providing your tracking number.'); ?> </p>
<?php
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is a syntax error. Try the corrected one below.

```
<p><?php printf( esc_html__( 'We are busy baking your products for delivery from our kitchen to your door. Any products ordered last week, including over the past weekend, are being baked this week and will ship next week. So, your order will be delivered in 3 to 10 days from the date of your order. Look for another email providing your tracking number.')); ?> </p>
```